# Validar login PHP

Tags: php, login

Boas, Estou a tentar efetuar um login no pequeno projecto e estou com dificuldade em caso seja o $login esteja correcto vá para o compras.html caso esteja errado aparece login ou password errados.

```
$login = mysql_query("SELECT Nome, Password FROM tb_utilizador WHERE Nome ='$Nome' AND Password = '$Password'");

if ($login = TRUE ) {


    header('location: Compras.html');
} else {

    // falhou o login
    echo "<p>Utilizador ou password invalidos. <a href=\"index.html\">Tente novamente</a></p>";
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente dessa **forma:**

```
$login = mysql_query("SELECT Nome, Password FROM tb_utilizador WHERE Nome ='$Nome' AND Password = '$Password'");

$res = mysql_fetch_row($login);
   if($res)
   {
     header('location:compras.html');
   }

   else
   {
     header('location:error.php');
   }
```

O **error.php** irá ser a página onde você irá disponibilizar uma mensagem informando que o utilizador e/ou password se encontram incorretos. No caso de não ser essa a página você apenas altera o nome mostrado. Apenas coloquei **error.php** como exemplo para página de **erro**